# Are security reviews in scope for stackoverflow.com?

Tags: discussion, scope

I would like to ask a question of the form:

"I have implemented a function that aims to preserve security property P.  Is there an input that violates these properties?"

Someone may provide a proof that, given my stated assumptions, P cannot be violated, or multiple people might provide very different counter-examples that show P violated.

In the latter (and more likely) case, picking a single correct answer might be difficult.

Are questions for which there might be many correct answers and where I cannot choose one as best for me appropriate for stackoverflow.com?

Is there another ( codereview.stackexchange.com or security.stackexchange.com ) more appropriate forum?

EDIT:

What I'm requesting is a white-box security audit, so the source code and test suite will be fully available to anyone who wishes to probe the system as per the [ground rules](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-java-html-sanitizer/wiki/AttackReviewGroundRules).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Michael Mrozek notes, if you have code, then you could post on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), but I would suggest posting on [IT Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) where you'd be much more likely to have security professionals examining it for known flaws.

- The [IT Security Faq](https://security.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)
- The [Code Review Faq](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

Answer (score 1):

I think CodeReview will be better for this case. Security - It's more about security than about programming, so I'd definitelly use CodeReview

Comment: Only if the question actually includes code (the OP was kind of vague about if he has code or not). Code Review kills any question that doesn't actually have code in it

Comment: @Michael Mrozek, I edited the question to answer your question.  In short, I will point to the code and test suites in the question.